# HTTP Error 404: Not Found. while installing NLTK data through Idle and cmd

Tags: python, django

Im on windows 10 and currently running python 3.5.1 with Django 1.9.1 also installed. While using the following procedure in both Idle and cmd prompt:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
```

The download started and got stuck at the following line:

```
[nltk_data]    | Error downloading u'panlex_lite' from
[nltk_data]    |     <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data
[nltk_data]    |     /gh-pages/packages/corpora/panlex_lite.zip>:
[nltk_data]    |     HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the URL to my browser and indeed no results coming. I have also checked with the firefox dev tools, and it logs an 404 error.

Comment: Well,@ Bora what do you suggest as a solution because what you just posted hardly presents as an answer but thanks for trying.

Comment: I suggest you can use a URL that points somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

i tried the following . and was able to install other packages.

nltk.download('all', halt_on_error=False)